# Foreach pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, pagination

I am looking for help in how to paginate my foreach output. I've looked at other questions and answers and cannot find a solution that works for me or that I can figure out on my own. Right now my code, which is below, outputs everything into table rows. My problem, of course, is that it dumps all data on a single page -- hence the reason I want pagination. I want to paginate for every 11 items on the page. The page is a magazine archive, and there are 11 issues pear year -- so every page is equal to 1 year of our magazine. The first page should host issues 1-11 and page two should host issues 12 through 22, etc. We have 10 years worth of magazine issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php $col = 0; ?>
<?php foreach (get_terms('term') as $cat) : ?>

<?php if ($col > 0 && $col % 3 == 0): ?>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $col++; ?>

<td>

<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'term'); ?>"><strong><?php echo $cat->name; ?></strong></a><br>

<em><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'term'); ?>"><?php echo $cat->description; ?></a></em><br>

<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'term'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" /></a>
</td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please tag your framework so others can understand.

Answer (score 2):

What framework/ application is this?  While I don't understand 100% where the data is coming from, you could try modifying your code to add a break when you hit 11 entries (or 10 when you are starting from 0).

```
<?php $col = 0; ?>
<?php foreach (get_terms('term') as $cat) : ?>

<?php if ($col > 0 && $col % 3 == 0): ?>
</tr>
<tr>
...
<?php if(10 == $col) { break;}
endforeach; ?>
```

That will limit this to the first 11 results of your foreach loop.  From there, you would have to modify how you select the data so that the second page starts at record 12.

Of course, it may just be easier to use limit syntax on your sql query, eg:

```
limit 12, 22
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful suggestion Joel. lolcat guessed right. I've tagged it. One problem for me will be modifying how I select the data on the second page, as you suggest. Or even limiting syntax. I'm pretty new at this so those recommendations are beyond my skills at the moment. If it is easy for you, and you are willing to recommend some code, that would be very helpful. For now I'll keep researching yours and others suggestions, so as to do it myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
get_terms('term', array('offset' => $page * 11, 'number' => 11));
```

Where `$page` starts at 0 for the first page. If you want page to start at 1, use `($page-1) * 11`.

How you determine what page to show is up to you.

See the `get_terms` documentation for more information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Comment: Thanks for this mcrumley, it does look good. But do you know how to work it into the modulus operator that I am using? I tried, working from your lead, but I can't get it yet. I am still researching. Thanks again...

Comment: What is the problem you are having with the modulus operator? It looks like you are trying to show the results in three columns. Does it not work?

Comment: A friend of mine was able to help me out. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I've posted the code that I used in my answer to the my question. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

this may not be what you were looking for or expecting but hope you or someone else finds useful. 
the following script does everything small configuration required [ps_pagination.php](https://github.com/harimaliya/appoinment-calendar-plugin/blob/master/menu-pages/ps_pagination.php) 
You need to include the ps_pagination.php into the pages where you want to use it and then use the following code to populate the information  on the paginated pages.
Hope its helpful.

```
 db_connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password')or die("cannot connect"); 
        mysql_select_db('database',$conn);
// mysql query         
    $sql_query="SELECT * FROM example ORDER BY id DESC";
// Create the ps_pagination object here
    $pager = new ps_pagination($db_connection,$sql_query,10,5);   

//The paginate() function returns a mysql result set   
    $rs = $pager->paginate();   
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {   

// table to display results here // modify here 
    echo $rows["title"].'</p>';
    echo '<p> '.$rows["post"].'</p>';
    echo '<p><span class="style1">By</span>: '.$rows["name"].' ';
    echo '<p>Date/Time</span>:'.$rows["datetime"].'</p>';                           
    echo "<BR>";
}   
// close mysql connection here
  mysql_close();

//Display the full navigation in one go   
    echo $pager->renderFullNav();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used to solve my problem:

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$segments = explode('/', $url);
$page = is_numeric($segments[count($segments)-2]) ? $segments[count($segments)-2] : 1;
$next = $page + 1;
$prev = $page - 1;
$issues_per_page = 11;
$lastpage = ceil(wp_count_terms( 'mag') / $issues_per_page) ;
?>

<?php wp_count_terms( 'mag' ); ?>

<table>
<tr>
<?php $col = 0; ?>
<?php foreach (get_terms('mag', array('offset' => ($page - 1) * $issues_per_page, 'number' => $issues_per_page)) as $cat) : ?>

<?php if ($col > 0 && $col % 3 == 0): ?>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $col++; ?>

<td>

<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'mag'); ?>"><strong><?php echo $cat->name; ?></strong></a><br>

<em><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'mag'); ?>"><?php echo $cat->description; ?></a></em><br>

<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'mag'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" /></a>
</td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
</table>


<?php if ($prev > 0) : ?>
<a href="/mag-archive?page=<?php echo $prev; ?>">Previous</a>
<?php endif ?> 
<?php if ($page < $lastpage) : ?>
<a href="/mag-archive?page=<?php echo $next; ?>">Next</a>
<?php endif ?>
```